# Too much smoke flavor

Tags: pork

We received several pork items as gifts that have way too much smoke flavor, these items are several types of brats, bacon and pork patties along with a mesquite chicken breast. How can I remove some of the smoke flavor?

Comment: If it's for example smoked ham or something similar with a crust, removing the crust would help since it holds most of the smoke flavor

Comment: You need to be more specific.  Not even clear if the meat cooked (smoked).

Comment: Smoked raw bacon/gammon can often benefit from soaking in cold water. Smoked gammon joints can be cooked slowly in plenty of water, which also helps.

Comment: @ChrisH that's an answer, not a comment.  If you ping me, I'll come back and upvote.  White wine does the trick as well (as this question is posted close to XMas)...

Comment: @Fabby it's an answer iff the OP has raw stuff, which they haven't yet clarified

Comment: Quick and easy shortcut is to not eat the items alone, but use as an ingredient in a larger dish - simple dilution.